# Maven property for current year

Tags: maven

I have a maven project that generates a properties file during a build. One of the properties I would like to include is the copyright dates for the project.

I have the property defined as such:

```
<properties>
    <copyright-years>${project.inceptionDate}-2016</copyright-years>
</properties>
```

I'm using the `build.timestamp` property elsewhere.

How can I replace the 2016 in the property with the current year, ideally by changing the timestamp format in just this one instance?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the [`build-helper-maven-plugin`](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/index.html) for this task. It has a [`timestamp-property`](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/timestamp-property-mojo.html) goal that can be used to store a timestamp with a given format into a Maven property:

> Sets a property based on the current date and time.

The advantage is that it doesn't force you to define a specific `maven.build.timestamp.format`, which would not be convenient if you intend to format the current date in a second way elsewhere. A sample configuration would be:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.12</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>timestamp-property</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>timestamp-property</goal>
      </goals>
      <phase>validate</phase>
      <configuration>
        <name>current.year</name>
        <pattern>yyyy</pattern>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

This will store the current year in the `current.year` Maven property. This is done at the `validate` phase, which is the first phase executed, so that all of the rest of the build can use it with `${current.year}`.