# Separating Maven timestamp date and time

Tags: java, maven, timestamp, pom.xml

I'm trying to create a folder structure for reports within the pom.xml such as:

/DATE/reportname/TIME

I'm able to get both the date and time together by using:

```
<maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd</maven.build.timestamp.format>
/${maven.build.timestamp}/reportname/???
```

Is it possible to also get the time in this situation separately?

Comment: Yes, use the `build-helper-maven-plugin` like shown here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39307133/maven-property-for-current-year. The pattern would be `<pattern>HH:mm:ss</pattern>` for `<name>current.time</name>` for example

Comment: This does not work for me, it just doesn't pick it up during the build for some reason

Comment: Make sure you place inside `<build><plugins><plugin>` with the `phase` of validate.