# Using multiple timestamp formats in maven

Tags: maven, timestamp, pom.xml

I have two properties in my pom.xml as below that I will use to filter a txt file:

```
<properties>
    <date>${maven.build.timestamp}</date>
    <dateFormatted>${maven.build.timestamp}</dateFormatted>
</properties>
```

I want `date` to be in the format `yyyyMMdd-HHmm` and `dateFormatted` to be in the form `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm`. Is it possible to use two different timestamp formats or is there an alternate way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by Tunaki in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39307133/maven-property-for-current-year) thread. Using the method he describes, you can build whatever format you need based on the individual components. It seems like this wasn't initially working for me because I was only calling `mvn resources:resources`. When I ran the complete build, `mvn package`, the correct changes appeared in the file I was filtering.